# How can I extract the URL of a Web Reference added to a C# project?

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-2.0, asmx

Let's say I add a web reference to a project), I would instantiate it like this:

```
MyWebService.MyClass myClass = new MyWebServive.MyClass();
```

Is there anyway to get the URL of this web service aside from checking the config file, e.g:

```
myClass.getURL();
```

at runtime? Does anybody have some ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web reference classes derive from [HttpWebClientProtocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.httpwebclientprotocol.aspx), which has a Url property. So you can simply use:

```
var url = myClass.Url;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the wrong class! That works just fine.